# Modules in omnet appear above each others

Tags: omnet++

Why when I create a project in omnet, sometimes modules appears above each other?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the NED file. Use @display to help you move the modules around

Answer (score 0):

Open NED file of your network as text (tab `Source`) and try to remove all lines that contain `@display`.